# while inserting record in database its inserting twice in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

while inserting record in sql server database. every time inserting 2 records, i think event firing two times. how to stop inserting records twice in ado.net.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CompanyName = txtCompany.Text.Trim();
        InsertData();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private void InsertData()
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kernelCS"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [tbl_Leads]([CompanyName])VALUES(@CompanyName)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", txtCompany.Text.ToString());
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have `if (Page.IsPostBack)` in your private method?

Comment: can you post your asp client side code?

Comment: i tried to stop inserting twice .so i used page.ispostback@RahulSingh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are firing the  query twice in your code by `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and   `da.Fill(ds)` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
private void InsertData()
{
  SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
  ConnectionStrings["kernelCS"].ConnectionString);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [tbl_Leads]
  ([CompanyName]) VALUES (@CompanyName)", con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", txtCompany.Text.ToString());

  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`
```